# Query mysql to find links without www or htttp

Tags: mysql

I would like to find a query to return the id of the contents that contains at least one `href` attribute value that doesn't start with `www` or `http`.

The table name is `contents`, the field name where to search is `content`

For example:

```
href="http://www.correctlink.com" <= nope
href="www.correctlink.com" <= nope
href="https://www.correctlink.com" <= nope
href="ftp://www.correctlink.com" <= nope
href="linkthatiwouldliketofind.com" <= yeah this one!
```

Every content could have multiple links inside (wrong or right).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you quering the html DOM, or a mysql database?

Comment: I think the tag should be `CSS Selectors`!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thank for your reply! I need to do a mysql query, i've take a look to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html but is no possible to perform a negative look ahead and i'm in troule :(